# Refrigerator freezer is building up ice on inside bottom floor

Tags: refrigerator

We keep getting at least 2-3" of ice on the inside bottom floor of our refrigerator freezer.

Comment: Perhaps you could revise to provide more information, such as make, model, age, previous experience. It's difficult to help knowing almost nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Two likely possibilities that I have seen over the years:

#### Blocked drain

This used to be quite common on GE side-by-side refrigerator/freezers, but maybe on others as well. Frost-free freezers aren't truly frost free. They create frost and them melt it away, it then drains into a pan somewhere to evaporate. If the drain hole clogs, ice builds up in the bottom of the freezer.

#### Gasket

When the gasket wears out, moist air can get into the freezer. The moisture condenses and then freezes on the bottom. If this is the problem replacing the gasket is the solution - usually fairly easy but also a relatively expensive part and specific to each model because it has to be exactly the right length & width.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mean the door gasket?

Comment: The drain hole problem is still common, the small hole leads to a pan mounted on the compressor, the heat from the compressor boils the moisture off. The hole can be easily plugged but is usually easy to clean out also.+

Comment: Many times the issue is ice build-up above the clog. You may have to remove the rear panel of the freezer to gain access to the drain hole. Shut the fridge off. I squirt warm water into the hole with a Turkey Baster.  Let it sit until it starts to cool off. Suck the water out and replace it with some more warm water. When the drain is clear the water should drip straight thru to the drain pan at the bottom of the fridge.

Comment: Yes the door gasket - a big rubber rectangle. Thanks EdBeal and mikes - your descriptions match what I used to deal with regularly.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you again.  That's great information.